# using feImage filter with internal svg not working in Firefox. Is there any workaround?

Tags: firefox, svg, svg-filters

When I was trying to develop some svg filters, I needed to include in the filter some internal svg I could interact with, and change dynamically. Sadly, I found out that the primitve filter feImage could only get external resources, but not internal svg.

After some research, I found someone who succeed to use an internal svg in a filter (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1538554). But this particular case works only works because it is used in an svg document, it's still not working in an xhtml document.

Because this issue with firefox seams to be pretty old, I was wondering if anyone found a workaround to use dynamic svg into filters ?

Comment: Is it possible to have something dynamic when using data url ? I'll look in that direction.

Comment: You can generate whatever data url you want whenever you want. You can also SMIL/CSS animate the data url

Comment: Ok thanks you very much for the tip !